# Is it possible to access the event queue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

I've some articles on how the event loop works. My question is whether there's some way I can access the current queue of functions that are scheduled to be executed. Just for fun.

Answer (score 3):

Not normally, it's all behind the scenes.

The only way you could do it would be to overload the functions like `addEventListener` and `dispatch` so you can add in some of your own logic and then watch them, but that would be a lot of work "just for fun".

Comment: and... it wouldn't truely be access to the callback queue. :p

Comment: Correct. You'd basically have to implement your own parallel queue to see it, and you'd only be looking at your parallel one which could deviate if not implemented correctly.

Comment: If you are trying to just play around with it so you can learn more, maybe the [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) in node is worth checking out.